# recyclerlistview inside a scrollview

Tags: react-native, expo, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, recyclerlistview

is it possible to use recyclerlistview in a ScrollView ? If yes, how it works ?

In my example it not working:

```js
...
  return (
  <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
    <RecyclerListView
      style={styles.recyclerlistview}
      rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
      dataProvider={dataprovider}
      layoutProvider={layoutprovider}
      scrollViewProps={{showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false}}
    />
  </ScrollView>
  )
};
```